# Addition in neon register

Tags: c, assembly, addition, neon, intrinsics

suppose I have a 64 bit d register in neon. lets say it stores the value ABCDEFGH.
Now I want o add A&E, B&F, C&G, D&H and so on.. Is here any intrinsic by which it is possible to so such an operation

I looked at the documentation but didn't find something suitable.

Comment: What is this "so on"? Can you state exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: actually I am doing some image maniulation operation. My image is in RGBA format. I want to add the r,g,b and  a components of two consecutive pixel.

Comment: Also , initially I tried to load the data using vld4q and use pairwise addition. But in a single pass of the operation all the 16 registers were being used, an error was cropped in.

Comment: vld4q_u8 will use 4 q registers. Even for a worst case scenario adding and storing them will require 2 more q registers. Still there are 10 more registers left.! How did you code to use all the 16 registers for such a simple algorithm! It would be better if you could share what the code you tried. It will also help us in suggesting you the best way to write it too.

Comment: There are multiple ways to do what you want, but how exactly do you want your addition? Do you want 16 bit results? Or do you want saturated 8 bit results? If so saturate signed or unsigned?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the addition to be carried out in 16 bits, i.e. produce an uint16x4 result, you can use vmovl to promote the input vector from uint8x8 to uint8x16, then use vadd to add the lower and higher halves. Expressed in NEON intrinsics, this is achieved by

```
const int16x8_t t = vmovl_u8(input);
const int16x4_t r = vadd_u16(vget_low(t), vget_high(t))
```

This should compile to the following assembly (d0 is the 64-bit input register, d1 is the 64-bit output register). Note the vget_low and vget_high don't produce any instructions - these intrinsics are implemented by suitable register allocation, by exploiting that Q registers are just a convenient way to name two consecutive D register. Q{n} refers to the pair (D{2n}, D{2n+1}).

```
VMOVL.U8 q1, d0
VADD.I16 d1, d2
```

If you want the operation to be carried out in 8 bits, and saturate in case of an overflow, do

```
const int8x8_t t = vreinterpret_u8_u64(vshr_n_u64(vreinterpret_u64_u8(input), 32));
const int8x8_t r = vqadd_u8(input, t);
```

This compiles to (d0 is the input again, output in d1)

```
VSHR.U64 d1, d0, #32
VQADD.I8 d1, d0
```

By replacing VQADD with just VADD, the results will wrap-around on overflow instead of being saturated to 0xff.